Docker compose up and the server exited with code 0
I'm working on a Java server homework and it has both a server and a db. They work fine when I'm not using a docker. Every time I try to use docker-compose up, it tells me server exited with code 0.
Here is my docker-compose.yaml:
version: '3.3'

services:
server:
build:
context: .
ports:
\- 8080:8080
depends_on:
\- db
environment:
\- POSTGRES_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/hw4
db:
image: postgres
restart: always
volumes:
\- db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
\- ./hw4.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/hw4.sql
environment:
\- POSTGRES_DB=hw4
\- POSTGRES_USER=postgres
\- POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
ports:
\- 5433:5432
healthcheck:
test: \[ "CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "postgres" \]
interval: 10s
timeout: 5s
retries: 5
volumes:
db-data:

Here is my Dockerfile:
# Use the official OpenJDK 17 image from Docker Hub
FROM openjdk:11-jdk AS build

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the Gradle build files
COPY build.gradle settings.gradle gradlew /app/
COPY gradle /app/gradle

# Copy the source code
COPY src /app/src

# Copy the database dump file
COPY hw4.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

# Build the application
RUN ./gradlew clean build 

# Expose port 12345
EXPOSE 12345

# Define the command to run the application
CMD ["gradle", "run"]

Every time I run docker-compose up:
Starting erss-hwk3-db_1 ... done
Starting erss-hwk3-server_1 ... done
Attaching to erss-hwk3-db_1, erss-hwk3-server_1
db_1      | 
db_1      | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
db_1      | 
db_1      | 2024-04-17 07:21:38.720 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.2 (Debian 16.2-1.pgdg120+2) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
db_1      | 2024-04-17 07:21:38.720 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db_1      | 2024-04-17 07:21:38.720 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db_1      | 2024-04-17 07:21:38.725 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_1      | 2024-04-17 07:21:38.742 UTC [29] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-04-17 07:17:10 UTC
db_1      | 2024-04-17 07:21:38.750 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
erss-hwk3-server_1 exited with code 0


Why does your command contain gradle, but your RUN directives ./gradlew? Can you start the container without compose? Can you exec into it and try to start your application manually?

Indenting your docker-compose.yml file would make it easier to read and provide help, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-application-model/#illustrative-example for an example

You should be able to docker-compose run server bash to get an interactive shell in a new container running your image, even if it doesn't start up on its own.  I might try using java -jar ... to start the application, rather than invoking it via Gradle, as part of moving to a multi-stage build.

Perhaps this is because the CMD in your Dockerfile is using gradle, not ./gradlew.
